# Promoting widgets in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, promoting

Qt creator has option to promote one widget to customly created class that derives from base widget - I want to use that to promote widget to class in current project. Qt creator asks me about class name and header filename, and those value go directly to **.ui* file, and then to *ui_myform.h* - the problem is that this file might be (and usually is) generated outside source tree (in build tree) which can be at arbitrary location, so direct specification of path in promoting window will not help. How to let QtCreator/uic know where to look for right header? Is it even possible?

Perhaps there is some Qt variable specyfying location of source tree, that I could insert in header filename field?

I am using self-compiled QtCreator 2.0.1 + self-compiled Qt 4.7.1.

EDIT:

> Why can't you just type in the complete path name of the header file?

What if I will move source tree, or even share it on the web - then everybody who wants to compile my project would have to edit this path either in Qt creator or in source files - both are unacceptable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The header file that Designer asks you for in the promotion dialog is **YOUR** own header file that define the custom widget, not the generated *ui_*.h* file.

Say you want to promote a plain `QWidget` to `MyCustomWidget`, you must already have a *MyCustomWidget.h* that defines your `MyCustomWidget` class included in your *.pro* file like this:

```
HEADERS  += MyCustomWidget.h
```

And in the widget promotion dialog, just type in *MyCustomWidget.h*. The purpose of it is so the generated ui header file (wherever it is) can include **YOUR** class definition.

Answer (score 3):

I already figured this thing out - I was promoting to my class, and giving header name that was self-written, that was correct.

The problem was that this (self written) file was not directly in the project directory but in `src` subdirectory (where all others sources also are), I am not using subdirs template, but simply adding them like

```
SOURCES += src/myWidget.cpp
```

The promoting option doesn't require full path, but it needs it as it appears in `*.pro` file - in this case switching from `myWidget.h` to `src/myWidget.h` did the trick - and it will work if I move or share it.

Answer (score 1):

If the promoted widget form `(.ui)` and class files `(.cpp, .h)` are in a Qt Creator project subdirectory and j_kubik's solution does not help it shows the error `("foo.h not found")`, try to use just the header file name for the promotion and provide the path as `INCLUDEPATH` in the .pro file.

Comment: I very that this works. If you have subdirectories were you place your .ui and your .cpp/.hpp files, you would need to add a INCLUDEPATH to were resides the header of the class