# Qt - Drag and Drop File into ListView

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to write a simple program (nothing special) which has a `QListView` and some Buttons.

**My question is:**
How do I specifically tell the `QListView` to accept Drag and Drop from the filesystem?

I currently have

```
setAcceptDrops(true)
```

Which is OK, but the drag and drop works on the whole (Main)Window. I just want it to work when the file is dragged into the `QListView`.

Why doesn't this work?:

```
ui->listView->setAcceptDrops(true);
```

The whole code:

```
#include "player.h"
#include "ui_player.h"
#include <QListView>

Player::Player(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Player)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    //This doesnt work:
    //ui->listView->setAcceptDrops(true);
}

Player::~Player()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Player::dropEvent(QDropEvent *ev)
{
    QList<QUrl> urls = ev -> mimeData() -> urls();
    foreach(QUrl url, urls)
    {
        qDebug() << url.toString();
    }
    ev->acceptProposedAction();
}

void Player::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *ev)
{
    ev->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

Comment: Have my answer solved your problem? If yes, please mark it a as accepted.

Comment: I have the "Player"-class, which inherits QMainWindow and sets up the ui and I have the class you suggested "MyListView", which inherits QListView. But I can't figure out how to put everything together. Can you give me a basic example?

Comment: When I was using custom widgets, I had to build my ui with commands in the constructor of the main window because I could not get widget promotion working because of reasons... I have never done it, but here is a [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) and some [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907766/promoting-widgets-in-qt-creator). Don't know if I should be saying it here, but there are even YouTube videos. Keywords: qt promote widget

Comment: Was the widget promotion successful then?

Comment: I solved the Problem with your suggested class. I created a pointer to the Object: `myList = new MyListView(ui->listView);` In the Constructor of MyListView I give the Widget as Parameter and set `setAcceptDrops(true);` . Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override these event functions for `QListView`, not `QMainWindow`. When you do `ui->listView->setAcceptDrops(true);`, `QListView` is now the widget that reacts to the drop events, by calling its `virtual` `dropEvent` and `dragEnterEvent` functions.

Make your own class that inherits `QListView` and define `dropEvent` and `dragEnterEvent` in there:

```
class MyListView
{
public:
    MyListView(QWidget *parent);                        // implement

protected:
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *ev) override;            // implement
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *ev) override;  // implement
};
```

You might also want to override `dragMoveEvent` as the [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html#overriding-proposed-actions) says.